# Altium: Traces under Pads/Vias

Tags: altium, via, trace, pad

New to Altium here, so my apologies in advances if some of my terms are off.  Anyways, I'm looking for a setting that enables traces to be highlighted when clicking on a pad or via.

[image: Image 1]

This is the result I would like that I have set up on a separate computer.  The pad was simply clicked and all traces on all layers that connect to it are highlighted, making it easier to ensure they connect to the center.  On another computer, I have this:

[image]

I don't know what this setting is called, much less how to configure it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Click on the via then hover the mouse over the via, and it will become transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Not a professional method but works:

1. Ctrl + Click on a via, which will highlight the whole net.
2. Right Click on the via and open **Properties**.
3. Do nothing just hit the **Cancel**.
4. Via is sent to background, select the track you want to modify.

It looks like this in Altium 15.

[image]

Once you move a track the via will highlighted and in the foreground again, hiding the track again underneath itself.

Comment: I guess that works, and I can go through every individual plane to send traces to the front.  Still trying to figure out what setting I was initially looking for.

Comment: Of course finding the professional way would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-click on a net will highlight the net.

Comment: While Ctrl+click on a net will highlight it, it won't make the via transparent, so the traces won't be visible underneath the via.

Comment: True, but that also seems to highlight the vias.  If I turn up the transparency on vias, I can barely make out edges and would rather have the white outline like in my first picture.   Edit* Exactly what I was thinking, Bence.